# python-devel not found in 16.04

Tags: 16.04, package-management, python

I am following [these options](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.1/d2/de6/tutorial_py_setup_in_ubuntu.html) to install OpenCV-Python from source.
In step:

```
sudo apt-get install python-devel numpy
```

> E: Unable to locate package python-devel
>   E: Unable to locate package numpy

After checking the existence of these packages in repositories [here](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/python/) I found that neither `python-devel` nor `numpy` exists. On the other hand `python-dev` and `python-numpy` do exist? Are these the same packages that I am looking for?

Also I realized that I actually have `numpy` installed on my system (I think using `pip`). Shouldn't my system be informed about this?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure who wrote that, but `foo-devel` is a seen in RHEL and RHEL-based distros. Debian and family use `foo-dev` or `libfoo-dev`. So these commands are all flawed:

```
sudo apt-get install python-devel numpy
sudo apt-get install gcc gcc-c++

sudo apt-get install gtk2-devel
sudo apt-get install libv4l-devel
sudo apt-get install ffmpeg-devel
sudo apt-get install gstreamer-plugins-base-devel

sudo apt-get install libpng-devel
sudo apt-get install libjpeg-turbo-devel
sudo apt-get install jasper-devel
sudo apt-get install openexr-devel
sudo apt-get install libtiff-devel
sudo apt-get install libwebp-devel
```

For most of these, you can look up the corresponding packages. I checked some, at least these are ambiguous:

```
libgstreamer-plugins-base{1.0,0.1}-dev
libpng{12,16}-dev
```

It's not exactly clear which of these versions the author intended to use.
Since there are ambiguities here, I suggest looking for a different guide.